# React-Native - Can't find variable: title

Tags: react-native

New React-Native installation.  I am trying to set it up.  In index.ios.js, I have:

```
class thingy extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={(
          title: 'Thingy',
          component: Main
        )} />
    );
  }
}
```

When I run this, the app gives me the error:

Can't find variable: title

I'm not sure why it's giving me this error.  Any ideas?

Main Component:

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC'
  },
  title: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  searchInput: {
    height: 50,
    padding: 4,
    marginRight: 5,
    fontSize: 23,
    bordderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 8,
    color: 'white'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#111',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    bordeRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});

class Main extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text> Testing the Router </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
};

module.exports = Main;
```

Comment: Can you show your `Main` component code?

Comment: It's in there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it looks like `initialRoute` should be an object, but you have it wrapped in parenthesis:

**How it is now:**

```
initialRoute={(
  title: 'Thingy',
  component: Main
)}
```

**Should actually be:**

```
initialRoute={{
  title: 'Thingy',
  component: Main
}}
```

Comment: Is this new syntax with ES6?